# How to merge int64 and object using pandas pd.merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes based on the "Alias Number" column name shared in the two dataframes.

One dataframe has "Alias Number" values as **integers** only, and the other dataframe as "Alias Number" values as **objects** because some "Alias Number" values have letters in them.

**Question:** How can I use the pd.merge function to merge based on these two columns without getting the following error to concatenate?

"ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat"

Below is what I have written:

```
ePPQ_FY17_file = pd.merge(ePPQ_NoNA_Alias, FY17_NoNA_Alias, 
                          how='left', on='Alias Number',
                          left_index=False, right_index=False)
```

Comment: Can you update some sample of `ePPQ_NoNA_Alias` and `FY17_NoNA_Alias`, please?

Comment: Certainly:  ePPQ_NoNA_Alias = 9023252412 and FY_NoNA_Alias = 622341251F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'`:

Input data:

```
# ePPQ_NoNA_Alias
>>> df1
   Alias Number  Value1
0             1      10
1             2      20
2             3      30

>>> df1['Alias Number'].dtype.name
'int64'


>>> df2
  Alias Number  Value2
0            1      10
1            2      20
2            3      30
3            A      40

# FY17_NoNA_Alias
>>> df2['Alias Number'].dtype.name
'object'
```

Your attempt:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='Alias Number')

...
ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns.
If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

So, cast the second dataframe to `int64`:

```
>>> pd.merge(
      df1,
      df2.assign(**{'Alias Number': pd.to_numeric(df2['Alias Number'], errors='coerce')}),
      on='Alias Number')

   Alias Number  Value1  Value2
0             1      10      10
1             2      20      20
2             3      30      30
```

Comment: The question specifies `One dataframe has "Alias Number" values as integers only, and the other dataframe as "Alias Number" values as objects because some "Alias Number" values have letters in them.`. Would it be better to convert that integer-only column to string and then merge on object columns, rather than coerce the non-numeric column to integer (which silently replaces any values with letters in them with `nan`) to merge on integer columns? Depending on which DataFrame has the string column, coercing can cause unexpected loss of rows.

Comment: `Alias Number` column of left dataframe is integer (show the exception) so you have to convert the other column to `int64`.

Comment: Ah, I see the comment now, so this works for this particular case. I'd still be more comfortable converting the right df integer col to string, since that doesn't silently remove values, just in case the code is later adapted to different data where it could make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, the first thing I would try is to convert the int64 column to string, then merge.

Assuming `FY17_NoNA_Alias`  is the DataFrame with integer dtype for column `Alias Number`:

```
FY17_NoNA_Alias['Alias Number str'] = FY17_NoNA_Alias['Alias Number'].astype(str)
ePPQ_FY17_file = pd.merge(ePPQ_NoNA_Alias, FY17_NoNA_Alias, 
                          how='left', left_on='Alias Number',
                          right_on='Alias Number str',
                          left_index=False, right_index=False)
```